# sliding in and out a UIView from the top (like a notification). How do I keep it static when scrolling the table?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UITableViewController. When I receive a message I want to slide a UIView in from the top, display the message for a few seconds and then slide back up. So far I have this code:

```
-(void)receivedMessage
{

    NSLog(@"you got a message!");
    UIView *content = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    content.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:190.0/225.0 green:86.8/225.0 blue:190.0/225.0 alpha:0.5];
    content.frame=CGRectMake(0, -87, 320, 87);
    [self.view addSubview:content];
    self.headerView =content;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        self.headerView.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 5, 320,87);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            self.headerView.frame  = CGRectMake(0, -507, 320,87);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [content removeFromSuperview];
        }];

    }];

}
```

The animation works however if I pull down on the table I can see white space above the message box. I want the message to float and still allow me to scroll under it. How I would I do this? Do I have to modify - `(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting self.headerView to content? You should just add the content view to self.view and animate it.

The headerView is part of the UITableView so that why when you scroll you see the white space.

Comment: headerView is just a pointer to content. It needs that so work can be done in - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView